# URL manipulation always returns a 200:OK in meteor - getting flagged as violation in OWASP-ZAP

Tags: meteor, owasp

I ran [OWASP ZAP](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) and the tool threw up a high vulnerability for possible SQL injection issue. Although we know for sure we do not use any sql databases as part of our application stack, I poked around and have have a few questions.

The payload that detected this “vulnerability” was as below:

https://demo.meteor.app/sockjs/info?cb=n6_udji55a+AND+7843%3D8180--+UFVTsdsds

Running this on the browser, I get a response:

```
{"websocket":true,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":false,"entropy":3440653497}
```

I am able to go ahead and make any sort of manipulations to what comes after the `cb=` part and I still get the same response. I believe this is what has tricked the tool to flag this as vulnerability - where in it injected a `--`  with some characters and *still* managed to get a proper response.

How can I make sure that changing the URL parameter to something that does not exist, returns a 404 or a forbidden message?

Along the same lines, when I try to do a GET (or simply a browser call) for:

https://demo.meteor.app/packages/accounts-base.js?hash=13rhofnjarehwofnje

I get the auto generated JS file for accounts-base.js.

If I manipulate the `hash=` value, I still get the same `accounts-base.js` file rendered. Shouldn’t it render a 404? If not, what role does the hash play? I feel that the vulnerability testing tool is flagging such URL based manipulations wrongly and ascertaining that there is some vulnerability with the application.

Summarizing my question:

1. How do I make sure that manipulating the URL gives me a 404 or at the very least, forbidden message instead of always giving a 200:ok  in a meteor application?

Comment: Did you test a development environment or a deployed bundle of your app?

Comment: well, adding a query (`?..`) does not change the URL per-se so most web server will just ignore it if it doesn't mean anything to them, i.e., if the route doesn't interpret it. So I don't your goal is meaningful. Now, why OWASP detected a vulnerability is a different matter, but I would try to find a different solution than forcing 404s when there is a query.

Comment: @Jankapunkt - I did a ```meteor build``` and the app runs inside a docker container.

Comment: @ChristianFritz - Thank you for your input. That makes sense. However, for closure, I'd like to understand what the hash is. All client side js files have a ```hash=``` appended to the URL

Comment: A lot of libraries use a random hash to ensure that the browser will refetch the URL from the server, as opposed to providing a cached version. Although I'm not sure, I'm at least 70% certain that this is the reason here as well.

Comment: @ChristianFritz - If I want to read up more on this? What do I google for?

Comment: You can take a look at the Meteor source, especially the tool folder and start with the build command. From there you will eventually reach the part of the code that does the hashes and it should be documented why.

Comment: FYI in ZAP you can specify the technology you know your app uses. If you tell it that you're not using and dbs then it wont try to attack them :)